# MySQL self join return all rows

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, join, self

Per the example data below, I need a query that returns every row, where if the 'contingent_on' field is NULL, it is returned as NULL, but if it is not NULL it is returned with the 'ticket_name' corresponding to the 'primary_key' value.

I tried self join queries but could only get them to return the not NULL rows.

example table data:

```
primary_key | ticket_name      | contingent_on
          1 | site preparation | NULL
          2 | tender process   | NULL
          3 | construction     |    1
```

All rows should be returned, where the in the 'construction' row return, 'site preparation' is input in place of '1' in the 'contingent_on' field.

Comment: This looks straightforward - can you add your query please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self left join:

```
select 
  t.primary_key,
  t.ticket_name,
  tt.ticket_name ticket_name2
from tablename t left join tablename tt
on tt.primary_key = t.contingent_on
order by t.primary_key
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mwP8X7wsf2m7TXDApkho85/0).
Results:

```
| primary_key | ticket_name      | ticket_name2     |
| ----------- | ---------------- | ---------------- |
| 1           | site preparation | null             |
| 2           | tender process   | null             |
| 3           | construction     | site preparation |
```

Comment: Thanks Forpas, perfect!

Answer (score 0):

It looks simple query:

```
select 
  primary_key,
  ticket_name,
  case when contingent_on is not null then ticket_name else contingent_on end as contingent_on
from <<your_table>>
order by primary_key
```